# How to display CJK characters and GUI in Java NetBeans?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, jframe, cjk

I am trying to make a simple app.I want to display a chinese character. But it displays a square.

[image: look on properties name]

Comment: click on the link to see the image

Comment: look on properties -->text the chinese character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font in netbeans obviously does not contain Chinese characters. Run it in the GUI and make sure the GUI is has a font that contains Chinese letters. Probably try a Unicode font.